# Bounded set vector spaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

On some notes I read the following:

**Neighborhoods** (balls). Given $x ∈R^n$ and $δ > 0$ we call spherical neighborhood of $x$ with ray $δ$ the set $I (x,δ) : =\{y ∈R^2 :d(x,y) < δ\}$.
Sometimes we denote by $I (x)$ a generic neighborhood of $x$.

$A$ is **bounded** if $∃I(0) ⊇ A$ It is unbounded if it is not bounded i.e. if $∀I(0)$ we have $A−I(0) \neq ∅$. Intuitively I understand the what a bounded set is. But I am not sure whether my interpretation of the definition above is correct. For instance, it looks to me that the following set $A=\{(x, y) ∈ R^2|y < -2x^2+2$} Is bounded according to the definition given above, in that there exists a neighborhood of $0$ which is a subset of $A$. But intuitively the set does not seem to be bounded to me. Perhaps I am not interpreting the definition properly. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Your reasoning is backwards.  You need a neighborhood of $0$ to contain $A$, not to be contained within $A$.  Also your definition of unbounded should have “not equal” to the empty set.

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 2):

Actually, asserting that $A$ is bounded means that there is a ball centered at $0$ which *contains* $A$, not that it is contained in $A$. And the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y<-2x^2+2\}$ is unbounded because, for instance, every point of the form $(0,y)$, with $y<2$, belongs to it. So, no ball centered at $0$ can contain $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $$A=\{(x, y) ∈ R^2|y < -2x^2+2\} $$is unbounded because for every open disk  $I(0)$ centered at the origin you have  $A-I(0)\not = \phi $

Your definition of unbounded sets is misleading because you have to change the emppty set to non-empty set.